# How to get HTML written to a new tab using window.document.write to render?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I have a javascript program that submits a form to a PHP page that collects data depending upon the form entries. I have verified that the data is returned correctly. In the following piece of the code, the success portion of the ajax call is shown:

```
  success: function(msg){
              var newWindow = window.open("_blank");
            var result = $.parseJSON(msg);
            var array = 
            newWindow.document.open();
              newWindow.document.write("<!DOCTYPE html><html><head></head><body>");
              for( var i=0; i<result.entries.length; i++ ) {
               var obj = result.entries[i];
               newWindow.document.write(unescape(obj));
              }
              newWindow.document.write("</body></html>");
              newWindow.document.close();
              newWindow.focus();
            alert( "Printout complete" ); 
        }
```

The tab is opened, and the `entries[i]` elements, which are strings, are written to the new tab. This is what is displayed on the browser window:

```
<h1>Age 1</h1><h2>Test</h2><br/>Test
```

The page source shows:

```
<html><head></head><body>"<h1>Age</h1><h2>Test</h2><br/>Test"</body></html>

The PHP page which filled the result obj contained:
...
    if( $age != $last_age ) {
       $last_age = $age;
       array_push($items,"<h1>Age $age</h1>");         
    }
    if( $age == $last_age && $event != $last_event ) {
       $last_event = $event;
       array_push($items,"<h2>$event</h2>");
    }
       array_push($items,"<br/>$data");       
    }

    $result["entries"] = $items;
        header("Content-type: application/json");
        header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");

   echo json_encode($result);
```

It appears that putting the h1 etc. into the strings to be returned result in them being encoded as <h1> etc.  They then show up in the source code for the page as '<', but the entire lines containing the `entries[i]` is enclosed in double quotes.  If where I write `unescape(obj)`, I substitute "<h1>Hello World</h1>", I get that rendered on the page.

How do I get the HTML to the page and have it rendered with the h1, h2, etc.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it was going around my elbow to get from my finger to my thumb, BUT, I got it to work.  In the PHP I changed to store a JSON array as each element in items, viz.

```
   $nameAttr = 'h1';
   $item = array();
   $item[$nameAttr] = "Age $age";
   array_push($items,$item);
```

similarly for h2 element and straight text element.

In the index.html page where it is processed I replaced the newWindow.document.write(obj), with:

```
               var objJSON = result.entries[i];
               $.each(objJSON, function(key, value) {
                if( key == 'h1' ) {
                   newWindow.document.write("<center><h1>"+value+"</h1></center>");                       
                } else if (key == 'h2' ) {
                   newWindow.document.write("<center><h2>"+value+"</h2></center><br/>");                       
                } else {
                   newWindow.document.write(value);
                   }
             });
              }
```

It rendered as I wished!  This seems inordinately complex to do such a simple thing as one might have many types of entries on the page such as <tr>, etc.  This method would require 'keys' for each html element and a subsequent handler for that key.  If anyone has a clue how to include the html tags in the PHP code, it would be helpful!